# Comparing normal arithmetic with pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am getting an error with a C++ program on a 64bit machine. The error is below. To understand the error fully i have tried a few variation of the program to see when the error/warning does not appear. With the variations i hope to understand it better.

The programs are compiled with

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra
```

> error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

---

This program give me the error. This is the pattern I see.

- sizeof returns size_t which is a unsigned long int.
- len is promoted to unsigned long int as part of usual arithmetic so it can subtracted from size_t
- Normal arithmetic with ptr and ptr2
- len is 10 so len - sizeof(unint32_t) will produce 6 which is a positive number

---

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "stdint.h"

int main()
{
uint16_t len =10; 
uint8_t number  =5; 
uint8_t number2  =10; 
uint8_t * ptr =&number;
uint8_t * ptr2 =&number2;

        if(len - sizeof(uint32_t) < ptr -ptr2)
        {   
                 printf("done\n");
        }   
return 0;
}
```

---

This code compile files with out the error above. 
A pattern i see from this is

- they are of the same type
- There is no integer promotion because they are all ints.
- the pointer subtraction must return an unsigned int type so it matches the left hand side.

---

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "stdint.h"

int main()
{
uint32_t len =1; 
uint32_t len2 =3; 
uint32_t number  =5; 
uint32_t number2  =10; 
uint32_t * ptr =&number;
uint32_t * ptr2 =&number2;

    if(len - len2 < ptr -ptr2)
    {
        printf("Worked\n");
    }
}
```

---

This program compiles fine with out the error above.
A pattern I see here

- There is integer promotion for len and len2 to 32 bit integers so
  they can be subtracted.
- Normal pointer arithmetic for ptr - ptr2.

---

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "stdint.h"

int main()
{
uint16_t len =2;
uint16_t len2 =5;
uint8_t number  =5; 
uint8_t number2  =10; 
uint8_t * ptr =&number;
uint8_t * ptr2 =&number2;

    if(len - len2 < ptr -ptr2)
    {
         printf("done\n");
    }
}
```

---

**Questions**

- is the subtraction of ptr - ptr2 returning a ptrdiff_t type which is 
  signed integer type? If so the 2 programs that are working properly have the left side types promoted to signed int because they are uint16 and uint8 and their values can fit inside a signed int. so the 2 programs that are working are being compared as signed int < signed int? But program 2 does not make that a valid answer because all the variables are uint32. If the pointers returned a sign integer on the right hand side and the uint32 on the left hand side returned a unsigned int they would be different signess so program 2 would have the same error.
- when integer promotion happens if the result is not assign to any thing does the take the type of what they were promoted to? Like sign integer above on the left hand side of the compare?

thanks for any help

Comment: If you have a C++ program don't tag your question as C. They are different languages.

Comment: `ptr - ptr2` is signed (it's of type `ptrdiff_t`). But it's also undefined behaviour, so the compiler can do anything it wants and you can't really deduce much from the result.

Comment: "sizeof returns size_t which is a unsigned long int." --> on your platform.  `size_t` is _some unsigned type_ with _at least_ a 16-bit range.

Comment: And you can't simply cast one side or the other because?

Comment: @alanstokes : how does the second program work then if is comparing against unsigned int (uint32)

Comment: @JohnSensebe :  i can cast the right hand side to uint32 and there is no warning. Just want to understand it before casting so i can make the correct decision.

Comment: Undefined behaviour includes printing "Worked". Or not.

Comment: You should probably run a test program that gives you the `sizeof()` of the types involved. I'm guessing `sizeof(ptrdiff_t) == 8` in this implementation, which would explain how 32-bit values can still be promoted. I would also expect the size of `ptrdiff_t` to be the same as the size of `size_t`.

Comment: @AlanStokes  the program compiled with out the error but did not execute the printf statement because the pointer subtraction equaled 1 which is not bigger than the left hand side.

Comment: @JohnSensebe : yes ptrdiff_t is 8 and size is 8.

Comment: It's important to note that comparing an unsigned value to a signed value is perfectly legal. The operands are converted to a common type via well-defined rules -- which will sometimes give surprising results. The compiler is treating it as a fatal error because you specified `-Werror`. Normally it would be a warning.

Comment: As mentioned already, `ptr -ptr2` causes *undefined behaviour* . It is only valid to subtract two pointers which point to parts of the same object.   I think you could avoid this issue but keep the gist of your question by changing the code to `uint8_t number[2] = { 5, 10 }; uint8_t *ptr = &number[0], *ptr2 = &number[1];`

Comment: It may be undefined by the standard, but this is a specific implementation we're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's time someone put what we've learned in the comments into an answer, so here it goes.

Under this implementation, `size_t` is an unsigned 64-bit integer, and `ptrdiff_t` is a signed 64-bit integer.

In the first comparison, `if(len - sizeof(uint32_t) < ptr -ptr2)`, `len` is promoted to 64 bits, but still unsigned, to match the `sizeof`, the result of the pointer arithmetic, however, is signed (`ptrdiff_t`). Therefore, it is comparing an unsigned value to a signed value.

In the other cases (`if(len - len2 < ptr -ptr2)`), `len` and `len2` are always less than 64 bits, so the result or the subtraction can always be promoted to match the 64-bit `ptrdiff_t`. Since we are adding bits, the "signed-ness" of the result doesn't matter (a unsigned 32-bit can sit comfortably in a 64-bit whether it's signed or not), and thus can be chosen to match the other side of the comparison. Therefore, no error or warning is issued.

Comment: thanks. ok so the result of the left hand side has to be promoted to 64 bit to match the ptrdiff_t. I thought the promotion happened only for + and -. Did not know it was promoted for <  and >